# Pointer to an array of class type and constructor with new

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, templates, constructor

So I am writing a class template and my class contains a pointer to an array that contains instance of class type .
My problem is with constructor of my class.
When in my constructor I use new keyword, it doesn't work properly.
The problem is that my array is not created when I use new in constructor. (It is like it's always a null pointer instead of an array that contains the instances of Node class)
I should also say that there isn't any error.
Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename V>
class Node {
private:
  V _data;
  unsigned short _size;
  Node<V>* _children;
public:
  Node();
  Node(V);
  Node(V, unsigned short);
  Node(const Node&); // copy constructor
  ~Node();
};

template <typename V>
Node<V>::Node()
  : _data(0), _size(0), _children(nullptr) {}

template <typename V>
Node<V>::Node(V data)
  : _data(data), _size(0),  _children(new Node<V>[_size]) {}

template <typename V>
Node<V>::Node(V data, unsigned short size)
  : _data(data), _size(size), _children(new Node<V>[_size]) {}

template <typename V>
Node<V>::Node (const Node& other)
  : _size(other._size), _data(other._data) {
  _children = new Node<V>[_size];
  for (unsigned short i = 0; i < _size; i++) 
    _children[i] = other._children[i];
}

template <typename V>
Node<V>::~Node() { delete[] _children; }

int main () {
  Node<int> n1;
  Node<char> n2('A');
  Node<char> n3('B', 5);
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advenced.

Comment: ***How*** doesn't it "work properly"? Please edit your question to include what happens, and what should happen. And if you get build errors, then please include the full and complete copy-paste of the build output, and add comments on the lines where you get the errors. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It might not solve the problem, whatever it is, however instead of `Node<V>*` use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just edited the question .... there isn't any error but for example if I want to intilize an instance of Node class as follow ```Node<char> n3('B', 5);``` , instead of having an array in _children attribut that points to 5 instance of Node, I get _children that is pointing to nothing (nullptr). I invite you (if it is possible for you) to execut the code in http://pythontutor.com to see exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: `Node<V>::Node(V data): _size(0),  _children(new Node<V>[_size]) {}` is problematic since it essentially calls `new Node<V>[0]`

Comment: @churill so what should I do to fix it????? any suggestion

Comment: @Mohammadreza What do you do in the default-constructor where your `_size` is also 0?

Comment: @churill so what should I set it instead of 0 ???? I don't see any other option here ... even if I delete entirly size, I have always the same problem

Comment: .... `Node<V>::Node()  : _data(0), _size(0), _children(nullptr) {}` Why not do it like this on the other constructor?? Ooooor the other constructor `Node(V data)` is meant to insert v and `_size` should be 1 not 0.

Comment: @churill sorry but i don't understand what do you mean by "why do it like this on the other constructor??" .... also ```Ǹode(V data)``` is a constructor that is used in case we forget to give the size of _children array and thus it instanciate the _size by 0

Answer (score 0):

I had copied your code into Visual Studio 2017 CE and placed it in its own header file. When I tried to compile the code as is from your question visual studio was giving me this compiler error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: StackOverflow, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\users\...\container.h(41): error C2039: '{dtor}': is not a member of 'Node<V>'
1>c:\users\...\container.h(41): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>Done building project "StackOverflow.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

To fix this compiler error I had to add the `declaration` of your `dtor` in the class's `declaration` itself.

```
template <typename V>
class Node {
//... previous code
public: 
    ~Node();
};
```

This allowed me to compile, build and run the code and I ended up with an exit code of `0`. It doesn't appear to me that there is anything else wrong with this code from a syntax or compilation viewpoint, but this doesn't mean that there isn't any issues with correctness, efficiency or concerns for memory leaks, dangling pointers etc...

---

**EDIT**

---

After working on this code for a while I had noticed some issues with your existing code:

You had these two constructors declared:

> ```
> Node(V);
> Node(V, unsigned short);
> ```

And you had them defined like this:

> ```
> template <typename V>
> Node<V>::Node(V data)
> : _data(data), _size(0), _children(new Node<V>[_size]) {}
>
> template <typename V>
> Node<V>::Node(V data, unsigned short size)
> : _data(data), _size(size), _children(new Node<V>[_size]) {}
> ```

The only difference between the two is when the size is `0` or not, otherwise they appear to do the exact same thing. In the first case what does an `int data[0]` give you? Or what does an `array` with `0` elements give you?

Another issue concerns the use of your member variables. You are using a prefix `_` which is bad code design because those are reserved for either the language and compiler or other things. If you want to distinguish between a member and non member variable. I like to use the post-fix `_` instead. Examples: `int non_member_varaible;` and `int member_variable_;`.

---

To clean your code up I removed the extra dependencies of multiple or redundant constructors. I also kept them within the class declaration since this is a class template. I declared the `dtor` as default. I also removed the use of `new` and `delete` by using `std::vector` and `std::shared_ptr`. I also added some accessory functions to retrieve the size and the data. I also didn't do anything with the copy constructor and omitted that completely as that should be trivial once you have your class operational.

If you know exactly the size of the array at compile time you can exchange `std::vector` with `std::array` and slightly modify the code. If you want this class to have sole ownership of the objects you can replace `std::shared_ptr` with `std::unique_ptr` with a few slight modifications.

For demonstration purposes I choose to use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>` as the internal container.

Also instead of trying to add multiple nodes to the constructor; I removed that dependency and just turned it into a function that allows you to add nodes during run time. If you need to add multiple nodes to this class when it is being instantiated then I would suggest using a `variadic template constructor`. The variadic constructor would also afford you to be able to add any Node type to the container with some slight modifications to the code.

---

Here is what I have come up with:

**container2.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template <typename V>
class Node {
private:
    V data_;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> children_;
public:
    Node() : data_{ 0 } {}
    explicit Node(V data) : data_{ data } {}

    void add_node(V data) {
        auto p = std::make_shared<Node<V>>(Node(data));
        children_.push_back(p);
    }

    ~Node() = default;

    const size_t size() const { return children_.size(); }
    const V data() const { return data_; }
    // no bounds checking just for demonstration purposes.
    const V data(unsigned index) { return children_[index]->data_; }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

//#include "Container.h"
#include "container2.h"

int main() {
    try {
        Node<int> n1;
        Node<char> n2('A');
        Node<char> n3('B');
        n3.add_node('C');
        n3.add_node('E');

        std::cout << n3.size() << '\n';
        std::cout << n3.data(1) << '\n';

    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**output**

```
2
E
```

And the code exits with an exit code of `0`!

Comment: ah yes. of course. I forgot to copy over the ```~Node()``` from my original code. but the problem isn't with ```~Node()```. The problem is with allocation in heap. I think that there is something wrong with my default construction and when I use new in other construction, it doesn't really allocate any memory.

Comment: When I get a little bit more time I can try to work on this problem to provide you with a possible solution that uses smart pointers that will help to make life simpler and to prevent less headaches and hair pulling. Managing your own memory is possible but it is tedious and has to be precise. You have to know if your code is going to be responsible for memory clean up or if the intended user's code is going to be. Also you have to assume the life time of the objects before hand. To properly manage memory it is an art and it takes a lot of skill to do it correctly and efficiently.

Comment: I think one of the issues with the heap in this case is that you are storing `_size` as a member of the class and you are trying to use that to define the how many `array` elements. This would have to be a `compile time constant`.

Comment: Thank you for your time ... I think too that the _size is causing some problems but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Thank you very much for putting time into this. The solution provided by you is very good and complete. But I would have liked to have a solution without using memory library and just by using simple pointers.

Comment: @Mohammadreza In that case do a google search on C Tree Structures such as linked lists, or Binary Space Partition Trees. The reason I mentioned C is that there is no smart pointers nor even new and delete; C has malloc and free functions. But that would teach you.

Comment: @Mohammadreza _But I would have liked to have a solution without using memory library and just by using simple pointers._ Learning how to use memory and pointers is always a good thing. And when you have learned how hard is to correct handle memory, you'll realize how useful are `vector` smart pointers and many other things in STL

Comment: @GianPaolo of course. The thing is that I am doing this for a university project. And this course is all about fondementals of programming languages (metaprogramming and generic programming and inheritence this year). So I would have really liked to have a simple class without using too much libraries. But now I see that it is better and also safer to use STL libraries.